# Search for duplicates large geospatial database

Tags: mysql, duplicates, large-data-volumes

I'm working with maxmind geocities table ([see here](http://www.maxmind.com/download/worldcities/worldcitiespop.txt.gz)), in MySQL (Windows).

This table has more than 2.7 millions lines (so pretty large).

I'm trying to find cities duplicates (in order to find the different spelling for each cities like pekin (fr), beijing...) following their longitude and latitude.

Even if I use left outer join, a subrequest or a complex where clause, but the response time is too long (it never ends).

Here is my last try:

```
select * 
from cities c1, cities c2 
where c2.longitude=c1.longitude 
and c2.latitude=c1.latitude 
and c2.cities!=c1.cities
```

Does anybody has an idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can speed up your query by not selecting `*` (I think `cities` is enough) and adding index on `cities(longtitude,latitude)` or even on `cities(longtitude,latitude, cities)` . You can also try

```
SELECT longitude,latitude, COUNT(DISTINCT c.cities) as num_dup
FROM cities c
GROUP BY longitude,latitude
HAVING num_dup > 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, however it works a bit faster, but not enough for me (190s). Moreover, I would have as result the different spell of a same city (having same longitude and longitude).

Comment: Hi,Impossible to create an index, it takes more than 10 minutes and the connection is lost. Here is my try : create index longitude_latitude on cities (latitude, longitude);  In fact, 3 millions lines is not so much, so what's wrong...

Comment: Creating an index takes some time, but 10 minutes seems too much. I hope you are not creating index while other processes perform DML operations...

Comment: Not at all, when I performed the index query, this is the only which access to my DB and which is processed on the computer. Any idea?

Comment: Can you post table structure (`SHOW CREATE TABLE` )

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. Here is it : 
CREATE TABLE `cities` (
  `Country` char(2) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `City` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `AccentCity` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Region` char(2) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Population` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Latitude` float NOT NULL,
  `Longitude` float NOT NULL,
  KEY `AccentCity` (`AccentCity`(5)),
  KEY `City` (`City`(5))
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: I'd recommend to redesign your table. First, add a primary key. Secondly, don't use `float`, it's not a precise data type (I believe `decimal(8,6)` is what you need for attitude/latitude). You can create a new table, for instance `cities2`, with primary key and indexes. Then import data from existing `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`. Finally, drop the old table and rename the new.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, I tried your solution but it does not work better... any other idea?

Comment: New reminder, anybody? If not, does it means that everybody wanting to do like me cannot do it...